# Check if a point is inside a polytope

Tags: r, matlab, polygon

I am looking for a function in R (or matlab) or an algorithm that checks if a point belongs to a [polytope](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polytope) which is define by its "triangular" faces.

So far, I have found functions for 2D and 3D (i.e. for polygons and polyhedrons) in [sp](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sp/index.html) and [ptinpoly](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ptinpoly/ptinpoly.pdf) packages.

Answer (score 1):

Try the [MPT](http://people.ee.ethz.ch/~mpt/3/) toolbox for Matlab: it supports different ways of creating polyhedron and has a function to check if a point is inside the polyhedron ( function `contains` returns `1` if a point is inside).

Short description is available [here](http://control.ee.ethz.ch/~mpt/3/Geometry/OperationsWithPolyhedra#SetContainment) and [here](http://infoscience.epfl.ch/record/186265/files/mpt3_ecc2013_final.pdf).